# Peculiar situation with a derived class using a line geometry

Tags: wpf, geometry, line, shapes, coordinate-systems

So using the line shape which has properties (X1, Y1, X2, Y2), uses the coordinate system relative to the space given to the Line element (that is, it is not absolute, or at least the one used by the containing panel). If you just derive from Shape and use a line geometry (in overridegeometry) and define two DPs for the start and end point, they will use the absolute coordinate system (the one of the containing panel) Why is this different? (Doesn't the Line (from Shape) use a line geometry?, but no matter what it uses (i.e. path) why should it make a difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is the same thing. When you are specifying the start and end point for the linegemetry it creates a geometry big enough so that the line with those end points can fit in there, relative to the geometry, if you want to relate the Line coordinates to the containing panel, you would have to take into account the Line's top and left properties.